# Using the helvet package with UTF-8 source

Tags: xetex, unicode, helvetica

I'm trying to use a Helvetica clone in a document I'm creating using XeLaTeX, and I need to be able to use a variety of fairly basic Unicode characters in my document (particularly the 'vulgar' fraction glyphs, like ¼, ½ and ¾).  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\textsf{Touché 3¼}
\end{document}
```

The selected font is Nimbus Sans L, which is close enough to Helvetica for my needs.  However, when I process this the PDF output reads 'Touché 3ij' – the 'é' works fine, but not the '¼'.  I've tried removing the `fontspec` and/or `inputenc` lines with no effect; removing the `fontenc` line causes the document to revert to Computer Modern.

I'm not wedded to using the `helvet` package, and if I load the font manually, I get all the glyphs I want, so the problem seems not be with my Nimbus Sans L font.  However, the font is no longer scaled by 95% as the `helvet` package does. This means it is perceptibly larger than the other text in the document. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Nimbus Sans L}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\textsf{Touché 3¼}
\end{document}
```

I don't really mind whether I fix the first MWE to have all the glyphs I want, or fix the second MWE to scale the font.  I've tried adding this to the second MWE, with absolutely no effect:

```
\usepackage{relsize}
\relscale{0.95}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: never use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex, the first just warns that it should not be used, the second forces legacy encodings and incorrect hyphenation. You can scale the font while loading it with `\setsansfont`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, but if I drop `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` then my document is in Computer Modern, not a Helvetica clone.

Comment: no. fontenc does not change the font family, it just changes the encoding and as T1 hyphenation patterns are not loaded in xelatex, the hyphenation will be incorrect for anyword using non ascii letters.

Comment: That's as may be, but commenting out the line causes the font to change.  Try it.  I'm not to worried about hyphenation rules as my editor insists I use `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`.

Comment: only by error so falling back to the format default `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`TU/phv/m/n' undefined`  the helvet package is only set up for legacy fonts

Comment: disabling hyphenation a strange choice but other than that using T1 encoding means using 8-bit fonts in a TeX-specific encoding so it negates any advantages of xelatex you may as well use pdflatex, as the only point of using xelatex is to use system Unicode fonts.

Comment: Your answer below fixes my code, so thank you for that.  But are you saying the `helvet` package is essentially deprecated in xelatex, if it only supports legacy fonts with encoding that break hyphenation?

Comment: it is completely useless in xelatex, and deprecated in pdflatex. The original `times` and `helvet`  are very basic simple packages designed to use the built in fonts in a 1980s apple laser writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can scale the font using the `fontspec` declarations, eg this ensures the lower case letters match:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Nimbus Sans L}
%\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
Abc \textsf{Touché 3¼}
\end{document}
```

Never use T1 encoding with xelatex, it will break hyphenation completely as xelatex only loads hyphenation patterns for TU encoding.

(I commented out the resetting the default family to make it easier to compare lowercase letter sizes)